# How to set a screen to not show on the bottomTabBar in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a screen in react native but I dont want that screen to be displayed on the bottom navigation. I want all the other screens in the navigation bar to be able to navigate to a separate screen, but the separate screen keeps showing up on the bottom navigation bar. How can I set it to not show there? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. Best solution is to use a stacknavigator for every tab screen and then using the screen in each stacknavigator so it will not change tabs

Create this component for each page of the tabnavigator

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Tabpage1 from '../TabPage1 ';
import Hiddenscreen from './Hiddenscreen '

var TabItem1= createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabpage1 :{screen:Tabpage1 }, //change this for each page
    Hiddenscreen :{screen:Hiddenscreen }, //this is the "global" screen
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'  
  }
);

export default TabItem1;
```

then in the tabnavigator

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator,createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import TabItem1 from './TabItem1'
import TabItem2 from './TabItem2' //etc,etc

var Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    TabItem1: {screen:TabItem1},
  TabItem2: {screen:TabItem2}//etc,etc,etc
}); 

export default createAppContainer(Tabs);
```

more info [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1591) , check [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/SyZElPlSm) for react-navigation 2.0